# How to call a Java method from a gateway in an Activiti process

Tags: java, xml, activiti, bpmn

I'm creating a process in Activiti that needs to have a gateway which should call a Java method and task should be closed

Mainly, I need to know how to call a Java method from that gateway

```xml
    < exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGw1" name="Gateway" />  

    // here i need to call a Java method

    < sequenceFlow id="flow3" name="" sourceRef="exclusiveGw1" 
        targetRef="rescheduleTimerEvent">  
        < conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">  
            ${input == 'pending'}  
        < /conditionExpression>  
    < /sequenceFlow >
```

Comment: How is this related to [bpmn.io](http://bpmn.io/)? Can the tag be removed?

Comment: @Jankapunkt, are you referring to the the ```bpmn``` tag? If so, it is not related to the application bpmn.io but to the BPMN standard, according to which Activit is modeling processes.

Comment: The bpmn.io tag was part of this before but op has removed it correctly.

Comment: @Kishore, do you want to call the method once the control flow arrives at the gateway (i.e., before any decision is taken) or when the control flow flows to another activity (i.e., after a decision has been taken)?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an execution listener to your gateway like this:

```
<exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGw1" name="Gateway">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:string>< "YOUR CODE GOES HERE" ></activiti:string>
      </activiti:field>
    </activiti:executionListener>
  </extensionElements>
</exclusiveGateway>
```

You can add such listener also to the flows.

Hope it helps.